# Content Migration

Tags: content, content-migration

After a SharePoint migration from 2010 to 2013, will the Content DB Id change or remains same? I was asked this question in interview and I said it'll be same. Is correct or not?

Comment: +1 only to get it back to 0 as I see no reason for the -1.

Answer (score 0):

You were correct, it does stay the same. The Id value is in `dbo.DatabaseInformation`.